# WebGL error when switching visualization

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-vl, webgl

I am getting similar WebGL error messages when switching CARTO VL visualizations:

```
[.WebGL-0x59c22054800]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0
```

```
[.WebGL-0x59c222e5500]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 1
```

These errors are being returned when switching from a current visualization to a new created one [as shown in this example](https://glitch.com/~viz-toggle-carto-vl-airship), but also when blending the visualization with a new filter [as in this other example](https://glitch.com/~checkbox-filter-carto-vl-airship).

I have seen the last option working fine [in this block](https://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/8025628d669f1d9d0647f658f5511774). What is wrong with my examples code?

**UPDATE**: it looks like the problem is related to the (GeoJSON) data source. Replicating the same examples but using `Dataset` or `SQL` works ([viz](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/carto-vl-toggle-viz-dataset?path=main.js:8:24), [filter](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/carto-vl-checkbox-dataset) examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug in CARTO VL library as reported [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-vl/issues/1395). Basically, when your data source is a GeoJSON, **it fails when you want to update the color or filter by any property that was missing in the first viz**.

Until they fix this, a workaround would be adding the property to the first (and second if you want to toggle) viz.

A. In order to filter by a property that is missing in your first viz, add a variable like this:

```
const vizCountries = new carto.Viz(`
  @country: $country
`);
```

Then you will be able to use the `viz.filter.blendTo("$country in ['France']")`.

B. You could do the same when updating the colors or the whole viz:

```
const viz = new carto.Viz(`
  color: ramp($population, sunset)
  @country: $country
`);
```

Then you will be able to use the `viz.color.blendTo("ramp($country, bold)"` or `layer.blendVizTo` if you have created a second viz instance.

Both of my examples are not working.